# Is it necessary for any doctrine mapped table to have an entity with the same name?

Tags: sql, symfony, view, doctrine, temporary

Actually I am dealing with a large volume of data in a Symfony 2.8 application and I want to make use of temporary views and tables to cross and query multiple tables with large data. So I am thinking of dynamically creating views, processing these data in the database, querying these views and temporary tables. But symfony generates the error

> [Semantical Error] Error: Class not defined.

How to make use of (create and query) temporary tables or views in doctrine / sql?

Comment: Each table your want to access requires an entity to be mapped to it.  You control the mapping so the table names and entity names can be whatever you want.  Views are easy since they are created in advance so you know their names and as far as Doctrine goes, views and tables are the same.  Temporary tables have no permanent name as far as I know.  Using them will be challenging in Doctrine.

Comment: there are these things called native queries and you can always use pure SQL. However, the moment that's supposed to create objects in the ORM sense, you need to make a custom mapping and maybe you only have partial objects, and then it gets a total nightmare. Anyway, have a look: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html